# Created a Function for a selected row in a grid

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

My grid is bined with a ajax call, when I select a row to edit there is a field named "Device_Type",i want to send the value of my selected row device type using Ajax to fill my dropdown list in pop up editor,how can I write a function for that?

```
  $("#turbingrid").kendoGrid({
                        //   debugger;

                        dataSource: dataSource,
                        scrollable: false,                          
                        columns: [
                                 { field: 'DeviceIP', title: 'DeviceIP', width: '100px', id: 'DeviceIP' },
                                 { field: 'Producer', title: 'Producer', width: '80px', editor: ProductNameDropDownEditor, },
                                 { field: 'Model', title: 'Model', width: '220px' },
                                 { field: 'DeviceType', title: 'DeviceType', width: '100px',editor: deviceTypesList  },
                                 { field: 'Description', title: 'Description', width: '220px' },
                                 { field: 'Username', title: 'Username', width: '120px' },
                                 { field: 'Password', title: 'Password', width: '100px' },
                                 { field: 'PublicIP', title: 'PublicIP', width: '120px' },
                                 { field: 'device_id', title: 'device_id', width: '120px',hidden:true },
                                 { command: ["edit"], title: "&nbsp;" }],
                        editable: "popup",
                        //edit:
                        //    function () {
                        //        document.getElementsByName("DeviceIP")[0].disabled = true;

                        //    },

                            edit: function(e) {
                                e.container.find("label[for='device_id']").parent().hide();
                                e.container.find("div[data-container-for='device_id']").hide();
                            }                                                                                  
                    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're only providing ability to select single row, my function below will return an array of columns and their assigned values.

```
$("#turbingrid").click(function(){
        var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");

        var selectedItem = grid .dataSource._data
        console.log(selectedItem);
  });
```

See the Dojo with a working example of my implementation...
http://dojo.telerik.com/EpeROQ

Edit (To accommodate question):

```
function select(e){
   var selected = $.map(this.select(), function(item) {
      return $(item);
   });

   console.log(selected)
}
```

Your Grid creation should look like this

```
$("#turbingrid").kendoGrid({
                        //   debugger;

                        dataSource: dataSource,
                        scrollable: false,                          
                        columns: [
                                 { field: 'DeviceIP', title: 'DeviceIP', width: '100px', id: 'DeviceIP' },
                                 { field: 'Producer', title: 'Producer', width: '80px', editor: ProductNameDropDownEditor, },
                                 { field: 'Model', title: 'Model', width: '220px' },
                                 { field: 'DeviceType', title: 'DeviceType', width: '100px',editor: deviceTypesList  },
                                 { field: 'Description', title: 'Description', width: '220px' },
                                 { field: 'Username', title: 'Username', width: '120px' },
                                 { field: 'Password', title: 'Password', width: '100px' },
                                 { field: 'PublicIP', title: 'PublicIP', width: '120px' },
                                 { field: 'device_id', title: 'device_id', width: '120px',hidden:true },
                                 { command: ["edit"], title: "&nbsp;" }],
                        editable: "popup",
                        selectable : true,
                        change : select,
                        //edit:
                        //    function () {
                        //        document.getElementsByName("DeviceIP")[0].disabled = true;

                        //    },

                            edit: function(e) {
                                e.container.find("label[for='device_id']").parent().hide();
                                e.container.find("div[data-container-for='device_id']").hide();
                            }                                                                                  
                    });
```

Edit 2: 
Just looked around the Demos too, see this Dojo which I slightly modified as it might help you get an idea of how to implement this event. Make sure to open developer tools to see the console.log
http://dojo.telerik.com/osIHU

Comment: how can I get the value of  "ProductName" in the popup editor of the following Link http://dojo.telerik.com/UfeYat